# Java - why would one use the state design pattern over saving the state in a variable?

Tags: java, design-patterns, state-pattern

I am very new to Java so excuse me if this sounds like a dumb question.

Why is such a big effort made when following the state-design-pattern (creating an interface, context and concrete sub-classes for each state) when you could just save the state of a given object in a variable and then make decisions based on switch and if-else statements later on?

Comment: "*[...] based on switch and if-else statements later on*" - Because we do not want those nasty `if-else` cascades or `switch`-walls.

Comment: It isn't a dumb question, but this has little to do with Java, and to answer it you could literally copy the [Wikipedia page on the pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern)

Comment: Also, if you keep adding thos `if-else`s or `switch`-cases, [you are going to make uncle Bob very, very sad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QedpQjxBPMA&feature=youtu.be&t=19m45s)

Comment: Note that overdesigning is problematic as well. If the state doesn't influence the code all that much then keeping a simple field should be preferred over the pattern. I like to create specific enums for state, because then I can easily view the state during debugging / in `toString()` methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`if`-`else` and `switch` statements encourage brittle code and responsibilities mixing.

Every time you add/remove/update a state, the same class and method has to be changed or a sub method invoked, so you increase the odds of introducing regressions in any state logic, whereas you would change one of them instead.

By separating the concerns, the states are not coupled; you could easily modify them without risking changes to any others.   You could even validate this with unit tests.

Comment: @Makoto  Thanks a lot. Really well written.